# Aggregate df1 per row of df2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, the first containing in the order of 10^7 values, the second ~ 10^4. The have the following structure:

```
# many rows:
# in this example, mean of group a is 3.0 and of group b 2.5
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "y": [2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4],
        "group": list("aaaaaabbbbbb"),
    }
)

# not so many rows:
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "y_pred": [2.9, 3.1, 2.4, 2.6],
        "group": list("aabb"),
        "model": list("cdcd"),
    }
)
```

I also have a custom aggregation function that I want to apply to `df1` to every group *and* model of `df2`. Currently I do this via iteration.

I'm looking for a way to achieve the same result in a more performant way:

```
def n_outside(x):
    "Counting number of elements <= 3 (applied after shifting by model prediction)"
    return x[x <= 3].size

for ix, row in df2.iterrows():
    df1_for_row = df1.loc[df1.group == row.group, "y"]
    y_mean = df1_for_row.mean()
    df2.loc[ix, "n_outside"] = n_outside(df1_for_row - y_mean + row.y_pred)

df2

   y_pred group model  n_outside
0     2.9     a     c        4.0
1     3.1     a     d        2.0
2     2.4     b     c        5.0
3     2.6     b     d        3.0
```

Comment: how many groups to you have? all of the groups have the same list of models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
df2 = df2.merge(df1, how='outer', left_on='group', right_on='group')

df2['n_outside'] = (df2['y'].sub(df2.groupby('group')['y'].transform('mean'))
                    .add(df2['y_pred'])
                    .le(3))

df2 = (df2.groupby(['group', 'model'])
       .agg({'y_pred': 'first','n_outside': 'sum'})
       .reset_index(drop=False)
       .iloc[:, [2,0,1,3]])

df2

   y_pred group model  n_outside
0     2.9     a     c          4
1     3.1     a     d          2
2     2.4     b     c          5
3     2.6     b     d          3
```

**Explanation**

- Use [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `how` parameter set to `outer`, merging on `group`.
- Use [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group on `group` and chain [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to get the mean for column `y`.
- The result of the groupby we subtract from `df2['y']` ([`Series.sub`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html)), we add `df2['y_pred']` ([`Series.add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html)), and we check if the result is less than or equal to `3` using [`Series.le`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html). The output series we add as a new column: `n_outside`.
- Finally, we use another groupby, this time on both `group` and `model`, and we get the appropriate [`aggregations`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) for `y_pred` (`"first"`), and `n_outside` (`"sum"`).
- Reset the index using [`df.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.index.html) and add [`df.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to get `df2` back into the original shape.

Timed it at a little under 70 seconds on a `df1` with shape (100000000, 2) and `df2` with shape (100000, 3), 50000 equal-sized groups, 2 models applied to each.

Comment: Factor ~10 faster than my version on real data. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure that this alternative solution is more efficient than your own solution but I leave it to you to try

```
def n_outside(x):
  # calculate the sum of all elements which are less than or equal to 3
    return (x <= 3).sum()

# Calculate y_mean for each group in df1
df1_grouped = df1.groupby("group")
df1["y_mean"] = df1_grouped["y"].transform("mean")

# Apply n_outside function to shifted values and assign the result to df2
df2["n_outside"] = df2.apply(lambda row: n_outside(df1[df1["group"] == row["group"]]["y"] - df1[df1["group"] == row["group"]]["y_mean"] + row["y_pred"]), axis=1)
display(df2)
```

Comment: Timing this compared to my iteration leads to approx. same results (tested on a ~20 mio. / 800 rows dataset). @ouroboros1 solution is ~10 times faster.